# Azure Function: Old code still running after a deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kudu, azure-functions-runtime

Right now I again faced the issue that old code is used on an Azure Function App even after the zip deployment through KUDU returns success.

Of course, that is after some 30 mins that I expect the new code to get loaded, not immediately.

[The issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3119) is marked as closed.

What is considered to be the best practice in this case:

1. Programmatically force the Function App to restart, say, through Azure CLI or Powershell Az modules?
2. Or there is another way to mitigate the issue?

Comment: Is this a v1 or v2 Function app? Which API are you calling to deploy?

Comment: Version is `~2` (2.0.12285.0)   
We use `https://${function_app_name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true`

Comment: V2 - happening with me as well.

Answer (score 6):

While restarting should fix it, my suggestion would be to enable "Run from package": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package. That removes the chance of having old files running as the deployment is atomic.

You'd set an app setting of `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `1` and continue deploying the same way you are today. The site will be run directly from that package (wwwroot will appear as read-only in kudu) so there's no unzipping and copying, which may be causing the issue you're having.

Note: it looks like we're still tracking the issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2636.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue lay in the CI-CD pipelines, where an out-of-date artifact was being deployed - thus the successful deploy, but the old code.