# Timeout error in Azure Function (with Visual Studio)

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am deploying an Azure Function from Visual Studio Code. Every time I add some new changes in the Azure Function and I deploy it, I am getting a timeout error at the begining (after a few minutes it starts working correctly).

The weird thing is that on my host.json file I have set:

```
"functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
```

and I receive the timeout error at 4-5 minutes after I do a request to de Azure Function.

When I check the logs on Azure Monitor, I can see a message that says: **"Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function"**

I have seen a similar error in this question: [Azure Function: Old code still running after a deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555159/azure-function-old-code-still-running-after-a-deployment)

So I guess that old files are still running. I have tried the same solution, but still not working, maybe deploying from Visual Studio needs another configuration...

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What's the plan that you use for your function? If you're using a Consumption plan, default timeout is 5 mins and you can set it up to 10 mins max. If you're using a Premium plan, maximum timeout is 60 mins. If you have a dedicated App Service plan, you could set your timeout as long as you want to, though making a function run for a very long time isn't advisable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that it shouldn't take so much time... I think that the problem is that are still running old files instead of the new ones. I have an App Service plan with 30 minutes, but it fails in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @jmarco have you check if your deployment succeeded? If your deployment failed it means it will not replace the old files you have. Try logging in to your function's Kudu service then goto ZipDeploy. By there you can see the last deployment logs and your files together with their last modified date. Also make sure that the function is stopped before doing any deployment.

Comment: the deployment succeeded. But the first minutes appearly is not working well because I receive the 502 error. Some minutes later works propperly.